# Google Sheet Script for Categorize Bank Statement download

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use a Google Sheet Script to categorize a bank statement base on the text that is in the description of the bank statement.

The code must run through the sheet (say sheet1) and column (say column B) with the description in each row of the bank statement.

It must then compare the text in the bank statement sheet (sheet1 column B) to a list in another sheet (say sheet2 column A) (that can change from time to time and change in length as well), and when it finds text that corresponds to the text in sheet1, it must go 5 columns to the rights (say sheet1 column G) and then insert the text (category) that is in column B in the other sheet (sheet2) in the same row as the text.

When no text is fined the cell in column G must be left empty.

Then the code must go to column H (sheet1) and put together the category first (column F &" "& Column B) with space and the description (column B).
The code must then insert the Year (2019 or 2020) base on the date in column A (=YEAR(A2)) in column E and the name of the month base on the date in column A (TEXT(A2,"MMM") in column F.

The code must then insert "Expense" in column I if the amount in sheet1 column C is negative and "Income" in column I if the amount in column C is positive - this must be in each row with data in it.
The code must stop in sheet1 A1.

I hope I explain it well enough. See the **[example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BtRFQYMK2X2g25F1WsQOnFIcT1fvcm3Y_5v9aLWWgks/edit?usp=sharing)** for a sample of bank statements (sheet1) and list (sheet2).

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.  The formula to pull the matching category, based on the words in the description, is:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",0,TRANSPOSE(
   QUERY(Sheet2!A$1:B,"Select B where upper(A) matches '" & 
     UPPER(ARRAYFORMULA(".*" & TEXTJOIN(".*|.*",1,FILTER(SPLIT(B2," ",1,1),LEN(SPLIT(B2," ",1,1))>2)) & ".*"))
     & "' ",0))))
```

I couldn't get this as an ArrayFormula, to fill the column, so you need to drag it down.

It works by splitting the description text into individual words, filtering out words shorter than 3 characters, and using TEXTJOIN to convert them into a string that can be used in a regular expression.  Each string ends up looking something like this: `.*TRANSAKSIE.*|.*FOOI.*`

Then the category table, from Sheet2, is searched, using a `Query(range,"... where matches '.*TRANSAKSIE.*|.*FOOI.*'..."` to find the category where the keyword matches any of the words in the above string.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kirkg13  

Thank you for this great formula - it is working 100% correctly.  

The formulas in the other columns I did myself.

I now want to create an App Script that will insert all the headings in columns E to I and then insert the formulas in E2 to I2 and pul it down to the last row with data in sheet 1.

Then I want that script to be available in any Google Sheet.

I will start with it and ask for help if I do not manage.

Thanks 
Milkyway